# Put a dropdown arrow in RadAutoCompleteBox of Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Is it possible to place a dropdown arrow in RadAutocomplete textbox, so that user can see what options are the list? Please see the screen shot[image]

```
  <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox
                            id="Variants" 
                            runat="server"
                            skin="Silk" EmptyMessage="Type here" DropDownPosition="Static" DropDownHeight="200px">
```

Answer (score 2):

The Telerik doco states it's not possible to browse the items in the dropdown area when using a RadAutoCompleteBox.

See here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox-difference-with-combobox.html

I prefer using a regular RadComboBox with the following attributes e.g.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="ddlVariants" AppendDataBoundItems="True" EmptyMessage="Type or select a variant" MarkFirstMatch="True" AllowCustomText="True" Width="200px" CheckBoxes="True" />
```

This approach still allows multiple selection and dynamic filtering of items, with the ability to expand the items to manually search if required.